# Canvas games - is it worth learning?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, gamecanvas

I am very into creating a canvas game, but im not sure if its worth the effort, and this is why...

Flash has Adobe Flash which is an interface for creating very complex animations, games and apps.
So im sure that a program is soon to come where, making games and animation will not require anny coding skills, it will al be done via a graphical user interface, pushing buttons and such.
So i am afraid i will put all this time into something that evantually will not be even necesary to achive the same goal.

What do you people think?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. But maybe the answer is no. Perhaps you should reflect on your question, and then you can tell us.

Comment: The more languages you learn, the better. Wider range of languages allows for better resumes, more experience, more options, more knowledge, etc. Learning canvas won't hurt you, it will simply give you more options. Also, even if a programming language dies, others will be born, and many languages derive from others, thus learning it may help you understand existing languages or to-be existing languages. As for coding without coding: far future. Computers cannot imagine (not yet anyway). Above this, coding allows you to create things that don't exist, what would be the point if all you had to

Comment: do was click buttons and add things that way. The closest thing to this that we have today is Dreamweaver, and I don't even use it. Coding from scratch is more fun in my opinion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that putting effort in learning is not useless, more if we are speaking about html5 canvas against flash whatever, because flash is dying and html5/css3/js is starting to rule in the same areas flash used to.

But more important is that you define if you want to develop a game or just make a game pointing and clicking

Comment: Flash isn't necessarily dying, it may be getting put on the back burner by HTML5, CSS3, etc. but it's still very relevant today and will remain for many years to come. Browsers will continue to support the plugin because a large quantity of older websites, and new ones too use Flash. On top of this, Flash (although it may not be supported by iOS) still adds the ability to be able to port to iOS. See this article http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html. For this reason, I would stick with Flash for animating because there is always the opportunity to port to iOS later on

Comment: To add to my previous comment, if Adobe continues to add iOS support (especially in terms of porting to mobile devices) the future for Flash is very promising. Many computer programmers/developers/etc. are comfortable with programming in ActionScript, which also continues to expand through the years. More functionality will likely be added to AS and allow for a wider range of options when it comes to programming, especially for iOS and other mobile platforms. Therefore, I would not say that Flash is dying, it's being reborn.

Comment: @ctwheels in my opinion is it dying yes, and badly, because you can reach the same results with html5/css3/js combination, but with better perfomances. Perhaphs it will transform itself to a new focus, but the actual one is doomed, I dont want to offend any actionscript or flash dev but animations on the web will be made of this combination, thats my humble opinion but I think I have good reasons to think in this way

Comment: Yes I would agree that it has somewhat died on the web, however it will grow in the field of games as this still seems to be the preferred tool for game creation among web-based game developers. Not many people know how to properly code with HTML5, CSS3, etc. to be able to make games yet, although this I agree will change and Flash will die as web-based

Answer (score 3):

Yes definitely worth learning. I don't believe any AAA games could ever be created without coding. Canvas is supported in all browsers and gives the users of your website a chance to try out something without fancy installations or crashed applications.

Canvas is also a good thing to put on your resume once you are good at it :)

Like someone else said, It's never a waste to learn something new.

---

Also, I think this question is more or opinion. If your trying to get a job on the server side for example: It may be more useful to learn some other server side technologies first.

Comment: What about the example i gave for a program like Adobe Flash, whic enables people to create complex games using an interface ? that was the main concern, that a program needing no coding skills will replace hanbd written code like Adobe Flash

Comment: Adobe flash is dead (or should soon enough)